# What strings satisfy regex: (^$)|(^.*\{count\}.*$)

Tags: regex

AWS ElasticTranscoder needs thumbnails to satisfy (^$)|(^.*{count}.*$).

What strings would satisfy this regex requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- An empty string
- A string containing the string `{count}`

`^` means the beginning of the string, and `$` means the end. `.` matches any single character, and `*` means match 0 or more times. `|` is the "or" operator and `(`/`)` work how you would expect in this case. `\` means the next character is literal.

So, `^$` is an empty string, and `^.*\{count\}.*$` means any text, followed by `{count}`, followed by any text.

Answer (score 1):

The following strings will satisfy the regex:

- Empty strings (will match `^$`)
- Strings that contain the substring `{count}` at any location (will match `^.*\{count\}.*$`)